# Image path from controller works in localhost but not in remote host

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, remote-server

Got a file upload controller with the path to the images folder `$config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'../images/menu/';`. My images folder in on the same level as the application folder. It works fine in my localhost but it's not working in the remote host. i.e, when I click upload after selecting the file it kinda resets the select file field and nothing happens. Already set the folder permissions to 777, still nothing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: is it working with relative pathing?

Comment: nope. Tried  `../images/menu` ,  `../../images/menu` , and `site_url()."images/menu"` with no success.

Comment: in `application\config\config.php` set this for your `base_url()` `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` now just call `echo base_url() ."images/menu/yourimage.jpg";` .Let me know if that works.

Comment: @CodeGodie, I have `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'; `  so that it works fine  for both, the local and the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

If images is on the same directory level as APPPATH, then surley your path should be APPPATH.'/images/menu/';

Also have you recursivley set the permissions on the directory, is menu writable?

Try some debugging,

```
if(!is_dir(APPPATH.'/images/menu/'))
{
    echo "Not PAth" . APPPATH.'/images/menu/';
}
elseif(!is_writable(APPPATH.'/images/menu/')
```

Comment: It is  Not inside the application folder it's on the root folder. But anyways thanks. I used   `if(!is_dir(APPPATH.'../images/menu/'))
{
    echo "Not PAth" . APPPATH.'../images/menu/';
}
elseif(!is_writable(APPPATH.'/images/menu/')){
    
    echo "PAth exists but not writable" . APPPATH.'../images/menu/';
}else{
    echo "PAth exists and is writable";
}`   And It says : "PAth exists but not writable" . As I said, I already set the permissions on the folder to 777. But I'm using a free host. Might it be that they  don't allow file upload scripts?

Comment: Being a bit thick, I didnt see it was codeignite. Perhaps try BASEPATH instead as that should be the path to your root

Comment: But did you set the permissions recursively, or just on images? If you have shell access, try ls on the menu directory?

Comment: Yes I set the permissions recursively. I still get the " path exists but is not writable". This is strange, as why do they have the `writable` option if there is a restriction in the free acct?

Comment: looking at your debug:  you swtich paths when testing if dir or if writable?
is_dir(is_dir(APPPATH.'../images/menu/'))
is_writable(is_writable(APPPATH.'/images/menu/'))

If I were you I would just hard code the path so you an confirm that is is a permissions issue.

Comment: did it, still echoing 'path exists but not writable'.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure needs FCPATH but would be use full to show your code. APPPATH is for just showing application/views/welcome.php that's all that would retrieve

Where FCPATH gets full paths.

EXAMPLE: `C:\Xampp\htdocs\yourproject\images/menu/`

`$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'images/menu/';`

Make sure the images folder is in main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. Although It didn't solve my problem, but i certainly learn a few things, I really appreciate. The problem I think is because I'm using `Freehostrunner.com` for testing so that I can show to my client which is overseas before he purchases the domain. I believe that they do not allow file uploading scripts in their free account terms. :( 
Does anyone knows of a free remote host that allows that?